# Exporting Kubernetes pod cpu/memory information

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes, metrics

I am running Kubernetes cluster 1.5.3 on IBM Bluemix, I would like to get the pod's resources utilization (memory and cpu) as raw data points. Is Kubernetes expose such API?

> ➜  bluemix git:(master) ✗ k cluster-info
>   Kubernetes master is running at https://x:x
>
> Heapster is running at
>   https://x:x/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
>
> KubeDNS is running at
>   https://x:x/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
>
> kubernetes-dashboard is running at
>   https://x:x/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) or [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) to achieve this. In many kubernetes deployments `heapster`is already installed. Both can be easily deployed in-cluster.

Comment: I have heapter installed, any hint how to access it? pull the data-points from it?

Comment: For a quick test you can proxy heapster locally and check the metrics. `kubectl port-forward heapster-v1.3.0-xxxxxxxx 8082:8082 -n kube-system`

Comment: Here you have a list of available metrics https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/model.md